# NGINX - allow access to specific URL only via a subdomain

Tags: nginx

I have a web page, located on `example.com/app`.

Is there a way to deny direct access to `example.com/app` and allow only via `app.example.com` by means of NGINX?

Comment: Please share the output of `nginx -T` so that we can see your full nginx configuration and give a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `example.com` `server` block, `location ~ app { deny all; }` (or similar):

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    location ~ api { deny all; }

<configuration for example.com>
}

server {
    server_name api.example.com;

<configuration for api.example.com>
}
```

Comment: But will I access example.com/api via api.example.com?

Comment: As long as `api.example.com` is in a different `server` block, yes.

Comment: Could you please add in your answer a server block for `api.example.com` which accesses `example.com/api`?

Comment: The subdomain and domain are simply in different `server` blocks. They are not accessing in the same way a browser does. The access is to the directories and files on the server. By configuring separate `server` blocks for the domain and the subdomain, access to files is easier to manage.

Comment: In your example I have to redirect `api.example.com` to `example.com/api`, because I don't have a folder named `app` to set in the root of `server`.

Comment: The `location` is what is requested to `nginx` by a client. With the `deny all;` directive, `nginx` will not look for the matched `location`. As far as what is actually in the server file structure is another story, because that is not what is being evaluated in this case. Even if there is no file or directory called `api`, `nginx` will still respond to the client with 403.

Comment: @TarlanMammadzada Please update your question by posting your existing configuration and `curl` output of what's happening and what you are looking for. This answer gives the exact answer that you asked for in your OP. If you have a different or additional questions, post it in your OP or create a new question so that everyone knows what you are trying to achieve.